# Совместная работа С++ при NodeJS

Tags: c++, node.js, многопоточность

Достаточно давно грезил подобными мыслями, и вот настала пора заняться этим.
Изложу вопрос как серию вопросов по совместной работе C++ при NodeJS.

Задача такова, что в идеале нужно сделать чтобы NodeJS и C++ работали в разных потоках имея собственный интерфейс общения. 
NodeJS занимается классической обработкой входящих запросов и рутинной работой, активно пересылая трудную работу на вторичный поток C++ и получая в дальнейшем обратно результат, причём поток С++ будет работать постоянно и иногда своевольно должен будет еще делать что то своё.

- Исполнение С++ кода ограничено ли в каких либо фундаментальных вещах, или можно делать почти всё что угодно как и в обычном приложении ?
- Поток С++ придётся запускать как Рабочего или доступны методы создания чистого потока изнутри С++ для самого себя ?
- Есть ли существенная разница в быстродействии или ограничениях между C++-Addons, N-API ?
- Вмешивается ли V8 как либо в работу кода С++ или всё вне API идентично натуральному :) ? В смысле: ручное управление памятью, утечки и тд...?
- Отладка С++ потока как понимаю будет невозможна, как и профилирование ?

Comment: 1,2,4 - вам достаточно исполнять требования по точкам входа и выхода. Дотянутся до того, что вы там внутри создаёте можно только через специфичные платформо-зависимый инструкции. Не думаю, что NodeJs будет прибивать любой поток, который был создан не им. В любом случае вы можете попробовать в "hello word" создать поток и посмотреть что будет.